# Uncaught TypeError: Failed to construct 'File': Please use the 'new' operator, this DOM object constructor cannot be called as a function

Tags: javascript, jquery

I was trying to create file object with

```
var file = File("path/to/some/file");
```

as recommended in the link https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Extensions/Using_the_DOM_File_API_in_chrome_code.

However, the bellowing error occurs

Uncaught TypeError: Failed to construct 'File': Please use the 'new' operator, this DOM object constructor cannot be called as a function.

How do I fix it and link a file path to the file object in javascript?

Comment: Well, did you try to use new File("..") instead ? Did it work?

Comment: Are you writing chrome code for a Firefox extension? From the first three sentences of that page: "If you want to use the DOM File API in chrome code, you can do so without restriction. In fact, you get one bonus feature: you can create File objects specifying the path of the file on the user's computer. **This only works from privileged code, so web content can't do it.**"

Answer (score 3):

That's indicating that you should call the constructor like this:

```
var file = new File("path/to/some/file");
```